# PTIJ: Mrs Potato Head in the Mikvah

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Can Mrs Potato Head leave her limbs and face intact when immersing into a Mikvah (to convert or become Tahor), or does her accessories, limbs, and face count as a Chatzitza, and need to be removed?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: do all of it's 'limbs" (including the detached ones) need to be immersed at the same time?

Comment: Do prosthetic limbs need to be removed?

Comment: Who said she isn't Jewish?

Comment: I am so glad the disclaimer was included on this one. Would hate to think someone would follow an answer to it halakhah lemaaseh...

Comment: When Pixar was working on the intellectual-property rights to include various branded toys in their movies, at one point they called a company and were told *hang on, lemme get you the lawyer for Mister Potato Head.* Apparently now we need the Posek (yoetzet?) for Mrs. Potato Head.

Comment: The question has now been partially obsoleted by further developments  The Potato Head family is becoming gender neutral; the announcement came out 25 Feb 2021.  Which leads to quite the conundrum: Given that the difference between Mrs PH and Mr PH is now solely the choice of body parts and accessories, should a Mrs PH remove all her detachable parts does the remaining PH body cease to bear any gender-specific state?

Answer (score 6):

In regards to converting - [The potato heads are all Jewish](https://www.jta.org/jewniverse/2017/the-story-of-mr-potato-heads-jewish-roots).

In regards to becoming Tahor, a potato head needs to immerse in oil, where the Halacha is not the same as regular potatoes.

Comment: That just begs the question. When she immerses in oil, how should she do it?

Comment: And while a woman shouldn't shower right after a normal mikvah, Mrs. Potato Head's immersion in oil is probably useless without a subsequent immersion in either applesauce or sour cream. V'yesh omrim ketchup.

Comment: @Shalom Ah!  So that's why some people use potatoes for Karpas -- they are dipped twice!

Answer (score 0):

There is a debate in halacha if she has to go to the mikvah in the first place since she's made of plastic.

Comment: If she was glazed then there's be something to talk a about...

Comment: Make her listen to a boring shiur, her eyes glaze over, take those off and put them in the mikvah ...

Answer (score 0):

B"H

If a vessel is taken apart then there's a mawchloykiss of it becomes tawhoyr automatically and might not even need immersion, but oychlin, food, doesn't have purity in a mikvuh, only water can be purified (in the daily rambam cycle sometime last week)

Blessings and success